# Facebook iOS SDK sample code doesn't compile

Tags: iphone, facebook, facebook-ios-sdk

I downloaded the code from https://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk

But none of the sample projects compile in Xcode. I have read the readme.txt and it doesn't help.

The error is: 'FacebookSDK/FacebookSDK.h' file not found

There is no folder called FacebookSDK, it's actually called src. When I change the code to say src the new error is: ld: framework not found FacebookSDK
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Can anyone download the code and get the samples to work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wrestled with this same problem for a while before discovering that there is a not-so-obvious file that is supposed to be downloaded and installed (versus just getting the ZIP file and its contents). The file is called FacebookSDK-3.0.pkg and I found it at:

http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=facebooksdk-3.0.pkg&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CEgQFjAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fgithub.com%2Fdownloads%2Ffacebook%2Ffacebook-ios-sdk%2FFacebookSDK-3.0.pkg&ei=Mg8kULzOLofgiALg14DwDQ&usg=AFQjCNF0i0Vkq_cPsOvfrs5nb_IOUR6XhA&sig2=kERJcdvR7UgAB6mr-RUi6w

(first link provided when searching for the filename)
I installed it and the samples work fine now.

Comment: I've the same problem after installing FacebookSDK downloaded from github (3.0.8). You can always find PKG on: https://developers.facebook.com/ios/

Answer (score 1):

[Facebook SDK 3.0 for iOS with samples](https://github.com/downloads/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk/FacebookSDK-3.0.pkg)

For more details https://developers.facebook.com/ios/

Answer (score 1):

If you install the package to another location besides ~/Documents, you need to change the Framework Search Path for the sample projects.

When you open the project up in XCode, click the project info (e.g. blue "HelloFacebookSample" in the file browser.

1. Go to the Build Settings tab.
2. Under the "Search Paths" section, find "Framework Search Paths".
3. Doubleclick the value and you'll see an entry that is like:

   ```
   $(SRCROOT/../../../../Documents/FacebookSDK
   ```
4. Double click *that* value and change it to point to the destination folder where you placed the SDK.

In my case, I installed the SDK to `/Dropbox/SDKs/FacebookSDK` so I changed the value to

```
$(SRCROOT/../../../../SDKs/FacebookSDK
```

(the 4 `../` are because it's relative to the HelloFacebookSample project)